# Setting namespace of a GitLab repository

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

This is my Ruby script for GitLab API, I'm doing commits and pushes with it: https://github.com/ivanove/my_works/blob/master/Create-Repo.rb

I'm using CURL inside of it to make requests.

So the question is, how can I set namespace of repository when it's created?

This is the command I use:

```
cmd = %Q<curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://#{@host}/api/v3/projects?private_token=#{@token} -d '{"name":"#{name}","visibility_level":20,"namespace_id":"group-from-1"}'>
```

I added namespace_id from GitLab [Documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#create-project), but it doesn't work.

Comment: what is "doesn't work"?

Comment: it doesn't create the repository in the given namespace

Comment: does it create the repository in the wrong namespace?  or not create it at all?  or something else?

Comment: it creates only the repository on current user, I need to create it on the given namespace.

Comment: @EugZol can you help me ?

Comment: @Euphor08 Looks like your `namespace_id` is wrong. Do you have any projects in that namespace already? If yes, do a `GET /projects` request and post a `"namespace":{ ... }` part for the project in `group-form-1` namespace.

Comment: https://github.com/ivanove/my_works/blob/master/Create-Repo.rb I push the new version, but it doesn't work,